# Prometheus - How to write query to see the change in the number of errors in the 1 hour interval?

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, promql

As I mention on the title, I want to find the difference of error counts in 1 hour interval.
When I use delta() or increase() function, the results are duplicated. I guess I have to combine functions. However I couldn't achieve that.

The example scenario:

Number Of Errors at 13.00.00 = 100
Number Of Errors at 14.00.00 = 120

So the result is +20

Thank you in advance for any suggestions or ideas

Answer (score 0):

Try running an [instant query](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#instant-queries) at specific moment of time (14:00 in your case) with specified time window (1h in your case). Something like the following should provide increase of metric `my_metric` between `timestamp` and `timestamp-1h`:

```
 curl http://prometheus/api/v1/query -d 'query=increase(my_metric[1h])' -d 'time=<timestamp>'
```

Comment: firstly, thank you for the answer. In my case, I will add an alert to this query so the query should be dynamic I guess. So I think instant query does not meet my needs

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain what do you mean when you say, with delta() or increase() function results are duplicated.

From your example scenario, you should be able to achieve that with the help of delta function with this query:

```
sum(delta(metric_name{}[$__range]))
```

Here, the `$__range` will take care of your dynamic time range.

Comment: “Results are duplicated” I mean, for example; exactly the same parameter is shown on the graph. Therefore they should be added up I guess

Comment: I am still not able to get entire context so if you can define your metric and labels, and give an example with help of that, then it would help understand the issue that you are facing.

Comment: allright, for example, there are types of errors like error1, error2 etc.
I want to get the change of error increase between 13.00-14.00
duplicated means when I run the query, error1 is shown 2 times(in some cases 3 times)

Comment: You should be able to achieve that using this query: 

`sum(delta(metric_name{}[$__range])) by (error) `.

Here the `error` is your label for the error that you're using in your metric.

Comment: I tried but it did not worked :((